# pppoe set up with VLAN configuration

Tags: networking, vlan, pppoe

I had a server which has pppoe configurated, it worked perfectly with my iptables rules. Then few days ago, I switched to new ISP, they brought me to problem with VLAN configuration.

They told me if I want to use my gateway server, I have to active VLAN0 or VLAN1 working with pppoe or I must use their modem which is already set up.

Here my config:

- eno1 interface for LAN.
- enp2s0f0 interface for pppoe (WAN) which is used by ppp0 interface after I run pppoe-setup.

The ppp0 interface error log running with new ISP:

Feb 24 10:13:00 sB pppd[6074]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests

Feb 24 10:13:00 sB pppd[6074]: Connection terminated.

Feb 24 10:13:00 sB pppd[6074]: Modem hangup

Please help me set up my server running pppoe with vlan.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve it.

All I had to do was creating a new interface which has type as VLAN and vlan id matches to vlan id of the provider, then rerun pppoe-setup configured to that interface. Sometimes the conversation between client and server has a little delay so we need to patient if the connection terminated, just retry couple times before we know it completely failed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you create that new interface?  What OS and way of configuring interfaces are you using?